# Flask, Jinja2 и не могу понять, как работает selected option

Tags: html, python, веб-программирование, flask, jinja2

Имеется проблема. Оформляю админ панель, страница делится на две части.

В левой - селект с юзернеймами

```html
<select class="custom-select">
  {% for element in userlist %}
    <option value='{{ url_for("admin", user=element) }}' {% if user==element %}selected{% endif %} onclick='location=value'>{{ element }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

В правой части селект с записями юзера

```html
<select class="custom-select">
  {% for item in content_list %}
    <option value='{{ url_for("admin", user=user, ID=item["id"]) }}' {% if item.get('id')==curelem  %}selected{% endif %}  onclick='location=value'>{{ item["name"] }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

На вход подается

> userlist - список вида ['Grigorij', 'Anatoliy', 'Ktougodno']
>
> content_list - список со словарями [{'id':id, 'name':name, 'etc':etc},
>   {'id':id, 'name':name, 'etc':etc}]
>
> curelem - id текущего выбранного элемента, который получаю с запросом
>   из аргумента ID, а затем передаю его в рендер шаблона так
>   render_template('admin.html', userlist=userlist,
>   content_list=content_list, curelem=request.args.get('ID'))

Так вот, второй селект, который с контентом, выбирает selected'ом все время первый элемент при том, что опытным путем было выяснено, что item["id"] у каждой опции верный, curelem все время имеет верное значение, при нажатии на опцию происходит переход туда, куда надо, то есть внешне вроде бы все работает как и должно, но селект ведет себя как то необычно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тест части вашего шаблона с Jinja2:

```py
from jinja2 import Template

template_html = '''
<select class="custom-select">
  {% for item in content_list %}
    <option value='{{ url_for("admin", user=user, ID=item["id"]) }}' {% if item.get('id')==curelem  %}selected{% endif %}  onclick='location=value'>{{ item["name"] }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
'''
template = Template(template_html)

params = {
    'content_list': [
        {'id': 368469, 'name': 'kliff', 'etc': 'welcome to ruSO!'},
        {'id': 198251, 'name': 'aiv', 'etc': '..respondent..'},
    ],
    'url_for': lambda x, user, ID: 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/{}'.format(ID),
    'curelem': 198251,
}

print(template.render(**params))
```

Даёт правильный результат с опцией **`selected`** в нужном месте:

```html
<select class="custom-select">  
    <option value='https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/368469' onclick='location=value'>kliff</option>
    <option value='https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/198251' selected onclick='location=value'>aiv</option>
</select>
```

Советы:

1. Проверяйте типы аргументов, возможно у вас в `curelem` число в виде строки, а в словаре в виде int или наоборот – при беглом просмотре легко упустить эту важную деталь.
2. А может вы забыли передать `curelem` в параметры шаблона? К счастью или сожалению, это не считается ошибкой, отсутствующий параметр будет подставляться как `None`.
3. Проверяйте получающийся HTML-код, а не только получившуюся страничку в браузере.
4. Старайтесь локализовать ошибку, копируйте и выполняйте отдельный кусок своего кода, проверяйте корректность его выполнения и типы значений на всех этапах (можно даже оптимизировать процесс используя двоичный поиск), так Вы быстро найдёте место возникновение проблемы и её причину.

<sub>И ещё, использовать имена вида `curelem` и `element` в одном пространстве имён для разных типов данных очень нехорошо. Лучше длинные, но внятные имена вроде `current_user_id`, `selected_menu_id` и т.п.</sub>

Comment: Спасибо огромное, оказывается, не учел, что item['id'] - бралось из БД как целочисленное значение, а request.args.get('ID') возвращает строку. Четыре часа мучился с попытками осознать в чем проблема. Еще раз благодарю!